Can an SDE be made to follow the flow lines of a vector field?
Let $V: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a Lipschitz vector field. Consider a one dimensional Brownian motion $W$ and the SDE
$$dX_t = V(X_t) \, dW_t,$$
where we identify $V(X_t) \in \mathbb R^n$ with the linear map $L: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ given by $L(w) = wV(X_t)$.
Question: Denote by $\gamma(x)$ the flow line starting from $x \in \mathbb R^n$, that is, the bi-directional trajectory of the ODE starting from $x$. Is it true that for all $t$, we have $X_t \in \gamma(X_0)$ a.s?
This seems intuitive, but I am not sure how to prove it.

If $X_t\in\gamma(X_0)$ then the trajectory of $X$ follows a fairly smooth curve. Where did now all the randomness go? It is more realistic ton consider the SDE $dX_t=V(X_t),dt+dW_t$ (with $n$-dimensional BM) and expect $\mathbb E[X_t]\in\gamma(X_0),.$

See Ito vs Stratonovich. It’s true for the latter but false in general for the former

@KurtG. Hm well I expected it to go into the fluctuations along the flow line.

@MartinHairer Oh I see that is unexpected, but I guess it would have to fail for at least one of the formulations...

In the SDE I was proposing Ito vs. Stranonovich  is not the issue since the integrand in the stochastic integral is a constant. When I think of it further: to have $\mathbb E[X_t]\in\gamma(X_0)$ (i.e. $t\mapsto \mathbb E[X_t]$ solves the first order ODE $\dot x=V(x)$) we want $V$ to be linear in $x$ to be able to pull in the expectation. The SDE in OP, when interpreted as Ito has expectation zero (martingale). When interpreted as Stratonovich it gets a drift depending on $V$ and its partial derivatives.

@NateRiver Recall that $X$ is a martingale in the Itô case, so it couldn’t be expected to stay on $\gamma$ if that curve has a local maximum in one coordinate…

@NateRiver: This distinction is one of the main motivations for the Stratonovich integral, especially in a geometric setting.  If $V$ is a vector field tangent to an embedded manifold $M$, then the solution of the Stratonovich version of your SDE is actually an $M$-valued process.  (I can't immediately find a reference with a self-contained statement of this, unfortunately.)  And one can even make sense of this intrinsically, for a vector field defined only on an abstract manifold.  But the solution of the Itô version will, in general, exit the embedded manifold immediately.

If you want a very simple example of what @MartinHairer has in mind, try $V = x \partial_y - y \partial_x$ whose flows are circles.  If the initial condition is $X_0 = (0,1)$ then in order to stay on the circle we'd have to have $X_t^1 \le 1$ for all $t$, which is absurd for a martingale.

@NateEldredge I see, it seems Stratonovich respects the geometric structure more, while Ito respects the probablistic structure more. Very interesting...
